# how convert function byte to dart

Tags: dart

i have a function like this in java

```
public static final byte[] f1504a = {48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70};
public static final byte[] bArr = {96, 50, (byte) 152, 96, (byte) 147, 80, (byte) 147, 18, 36, 17, 1, 32, (byte) 145, 17, 4, 84, 0, (byte) 145, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 116, 87, (byte) 175, 116, 7, (byte) 174, (byte) 206, (byte) 244, 15, (byte) 227, (byte) 162, 68, 9, (byte) 244, (byte) 236, 73, 59, 3, 84, 120, (byte) 132, (byte) 182, (byte) 174, (byte) 176, 80, (byte) 195, 0, 17, 1, 32, 3, (byte) 246, 61, 13, (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 144, 0};

public static String b(byte[] bArr, int i) {
    byte[] bArr2 = new byte[(i * 2)];
    int i2 = 0;
    int i3 = 0;
    for (byte b2 : bArr) {
        if (i2 >= i) {
            break;
        }
        i2++;
        int i4 = b2 & 255;
        int i5 = i3 + 1;
        byte[] bArr3 = f1504a;
        bArr2[i3] = bArr3[i4 >>> 4];
        i3 = i5 + 1;
        bArr2[i5] = bArr3[i4 & 15];
    }
    return new String(bArr2);
}
```

b(bArr, 8);

RESULT IS :  6032986093509312

how to convert to dart or flutter.

thanks for answering i'm very appreciate

Comment: Uint8List is the datatype you are looking for in dart.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Asking for someone to write code for you is not really what this site is for.  I would suggest rewriting your question to include your dart implementation, in whatever functional state it exists, what you've tried so far, what worked/didn't, etc.  Specific problems will get specific answers, general "how do I do this" queries are better suited for other sites.

Comment: Do you understand what the code is doing? As far as I can see, it is simply taking the first `i` bytes from `bArr` and **formatting the bytes as hex**. So try searching the web for code that does that in dart or flutter.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from julemand101 is a perfect translation of the Java code.
A more idiomatic Dart version could be something like:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

final byteTable = Uint8List.fromList([
  96, 50, 152, 96, 147, 80, 147, 18, 36, 17, 1, 32, 145, 17, 4, 84, 0, 145, //
  3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 116, 87, 175, 116, 7, 174, 206, 244, 15, 227, //
  162, 68, 9, 244, 236, 73, 59, 3, 84, 120, 132, 182, 174, 176, 80, 195, 0, //
  17, 1, 32, 3, 246, 61, 13, 255, 255, 144, 0
]);

// The hex representation of the first [length] bytes of [bytes].
String toHex(Uint8List bytes, int length) {
  const hexDigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  final resultBytes = Uint8List(length * 2);
  if (length > bytes.length) length = bytes.length;
  for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var byte = bytes[i];
    resultBytes[j++] = hexDigits.codeUnitAt(byte >> 4);
    resultBytes[j++] = hexDigits.codeUnitAt(byte & 15);
  }
  return String.fromCharCodes(resultBytes);
}

void main() {
  print(toHex(byteTable, 8)); // 6032986093509312
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the comments you got on your question. You should not expect Stackoverflow to just be a service where you can get other people to do your work.

When that said, I got some spare time and ended up writing a solution in Dart for your code as some kind of puzzle. Not entirely sure if it works the same as your Java code but it works for that one example you have provided:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

Uint8List f1504a = Uint8List.fromList(
    [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]);
Uint8List bArr = Uint8List.fromList([
  96, 50, 152, 96, 147, 80, 147, 18, 36, 17, 1, 32, 145, 17, 4, 84, 0, 145, //
  3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 116, 87, 175, 116, 7, 174, 206, 244, 15, 227, //
  162, 68, 9, 244, 236, 73, 59, 3, 84, 120, 132, 182, 174, 176, 80, 195, 0, //
  17, 1, 32, 3, 246, 61, 13, 255, 255, 144, 0
]);

String b(Uint8List bArr, int i) {
  final bArr2 = Uint8List(i * 2);
  var i2 = 0, i3 = 0;

  for (final b2 in bArr) {
    if (i2 >= i) {
      break;
    }
    i2++;

    final i4 = b2 & 255;
    final i5 = i3 + 1;
    final bArr3 = f1504a;
    bArr2[i3] = bArr3[i4 >> 4];
    i3 = i5 + 1;
    bArr2[i5] = bArr3[i4 & 15];
  }

  return String.fromCharCodes(bArr2);
}

void main() {
  print(b(bArr, 8)); // 6032986093509312
}
```